# Need idea to create the dynamic menu strip in windows application using data table

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, menustrip

Menu style:

File   . Tool
-file1   -tool1
-file2   -tool2
-file3   -tool3

datable contains the rows like.

col1   col2
------------
File   file1
File   file2
File   file3
Tool   tool1
Tool   tool2
Tool   tool3

How to bind my data table value into menu strip dynamically i get my data table values from database dynamically.

Based on my data table value the menu should display in my form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building the menu from a database table, you can security trim it by joining it to another table or view that excludes records on the basis of the permissions set.

The diagram below illustrates the basics of setting up role permissions for users, and contains a couple of other tables for security trimming individual controls on the form as well.

[**Controls Based Security in a Windows Forms Application**](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/windows-forms/controls-based-security-in-a-windows-forms-application/)

[image]